# When asking for an input, my boolean requires the input to be repeated before changing the value

Tags: python

I am making a program through a tutorial video and the code is either starting, stopping or exiting a car. Part of the program is to make it so if the car is either already started, or already stopped, you tell them that in the program. My program will tell the user that the car is already started or stopped, but after I told it stop two times, and not just once. 
Hopefully somebody could describe maybe the issue between the relationship of my while loop and the boolean inside my if statements?

```
action = ""
started = False
while action != 'exit':
    action = input("Type either start, stop, exit to work this car: ").lower()
    if action == "start":
        if started:
            print("The car is already started")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Congrats you started the car! You can now either stop the car or exit the car!")
            action == input("Type either stop or exit to work this car: ")  
    elif action == "stop":
        if not started:
            print("You already stopped the car")
        else:
            started = False
            print("Congrats you stopped the car! You can now exit the car!")
            action = input("Either start the car again or exit the car: ")
    elif action == "exit":
        print("Congrats you exited the car!")
        break
    else: 
        action = input("You typed an invalid response, type either start, stop or exit:")
pprint("The end")
```

Comment: You need to remove all `action == input(..)` lines from inside every `if` statements.
You need to have only one at the top under `while`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case where the car has already been started, and the user has now entered 'stop'. That puts us in the `else` block here:

```
elif action == "stop":
    if not started:
        print("You already stopped the car")
    else:  # <-- here
        started = False
        print("Congrats you stopped the car! You can now exit the car!")
        action = input("Either start the car again or exit the car: ")
```

The last line prompts the user to enter a new command, which resets `action` and brings you back to the top of the loop, where you immediately prompt the user for a new command:

```
action = input("Type either start, stop, exit to work this car: ").lower()
```

In other words, your code "forgets" what the user typed inside the 'stop' block, prompting them for a new command without processing the original entry.

You can resolve this pretty easily by moving the very first `input` line into one of the conditional blocks - the `else`. This has the added benefit of allowing you to keep the precision of prompting the user with the message that applies to their case (e.g. "Either start the car again or exit the car" when the user has just entered "stop"). Should look something like this:

```
action = ""
started = False
while True:
    if action == "start":
        if started:
            print("The car is already started")
        else:
            started = True
            print("Congrats you started the car! You can now either stop the car or exit the car!")
        action = input("Type either stop or exit to work this car: ")  
    elif action == "stop":
        if not started:
            print("You already stopped the car")
        else:
            started = False
            print("Congrats you stopped the car! You can now exit the car!")
        action = input("Either start the car again or exit the car: ")
    elif action == "exit":
        print("Congrats you exited the car!")
        break
    else:
        if action:
            print("You typed an invalid response.")
        action = input("Type either start, stop, exit to work this car: ").lower()
print("The end")
```

Note this will work fine on the first pass, since `action = ""` will bring you straight down to the new `else` block.

Comment: You could get input outside the start of the while loop too, and keep the rest

Comment: True, except you still need the main `input` inside the `else` to handle bad entries. I'm not sure there's an advantage to duplicating that line.

Comment: So I think that fixed the value forgetting itself and reprompting inside the while loop, but for some reason when it says "the car is already started" it says it in an infinite loop, but I dont get that because theres no for loop. I placed an exit() inside the if loop but then it just breaks from the entire while loop and stops.

Comment: Ah apologies, I made an indentation mistake. Should be good now

Answer (score 0):

Let me correct your code

```
action = ""
started = 0 
while action != 'exit':
    action = input("Type either start, stop, exit to work this car: ").lower()
    if action == "start":
        if started:
            print("The car is already started")
        else:
            started = 2
            print("Congrats you started the car! You can now either stop the car or exit the car!")
            action = input("Type either stop or exit to work this car: ").lower()  
    elif action == "stop":
        if started == 2:
            started = 1
        elif started == 0:
            print("You already stopped the car")
        else:
            started = 0
            print("Congrats you stopped the car! You can now exit the car!")
            action = input("Either start the car again or exit the car: ").lower()
    elif action == "exit":
        print("Congrats you exited the car!")
        break
    else: 
        action = input("You typed an invalid response, type either start, stop or exit:").lower()
print("The end")
```

You need to change `action == input(...)` to `action = input(...)`

Comment: the input for the action is still repeated

Comment: I don't understand your question,

Comment: part of the question says "I told it stop two times, and not just once"

Comment: oh, ok. let me fix that